# Getting error after installing sql server 08 Express edition

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2008-express, database-connectivity

I have installed SQL server 08 express edition and then tried to connect using SQL server management studio, but getting below error:

> ### TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to My-PC\SQLSERVER.
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network
>   Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft
>   SQL Server, Error: -1)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-1&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### OK

any clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are referencing the correct SQL Server name?  I think the default instance name is SQLEXPRESS.  So, you might try connecting to .\SQLEXPRESS, where "." represents the local computer.

Comment: @Wondering - I don't think so; but I'll keep a separate count.  Good luck.